# How to plot a trendline on scatter-plot matplotlib based on KDE?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently trying to plot a trend-line plot on my scatter-plot in MatPlotLib.

I am aware of numpy `polyfit` function. It does not do what I want.

So here what I have so far:

```
plot = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)) #Set up the size of the figure

cmap = "viridis" #Set up the color map 

plt.scatter(samples[1], samples[0], s=0.1, c=density_sm, cmap=cmap) #Plot the Cross-Plot

plt.colorbar().set_label('Density of points')

plt.axis('scaled')
plt.xlim(-0.3,0.3)
plt.ylim(-0.3,0.3)
plt.xlabel("Intercept")
plt.ylabel("Gradient")

plt.axhline(0, color='green', alpha=0.5, linestyle="--")
plt.axvline(0, color='green', alpha=0.5, linestyle="--")

#Trend-line_1
z = np.polyfit(samples[1], samples[0], 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(samples[0],p(samples[0]),color="#CC3333", linewidth=0.5)

#Trend-line_2
reg = sm.WLS(samples[0], samples[1]).fit()
plt.plot(samples[1], reg.fittedvalues)
```

And here is the result:

[Scatter-plot with trends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZrqr.jpg)

What I want is:

[Scatter-Plot_desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaOTU.jpg)

Trend can easily be seen, but the question is what function to use?

Comment: can you add a representative dataset & image of your expected result?

Comment: My dataset is about 0.5 Gb, how can I substitute it?

Comment: To me `polyfit` seems appropriate to use in this case. Maybe it would help to tell about the reasons you have not to use it. There are of course other tools to fit data, the easiest one in the statsmodel package being an [ordinary least squares](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/regression.html) fit. Also the tool you are using (you didn't tell which one it is) might have one available. You could also simply use the [`seaborn.regplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) with the evident drawback that you don't get any information on your fit.

Comment: Could you post how you use polyfit? Polyfit uses linear fitting, which should always find the optimal parameters. Therefore it seems odd that in your case the fit looks off. Are you sure you are plotting the result correctly?

Comment: I have updated the code and first picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour of polyfit is as excepted and the result is correct. The problem is that polyfit does not do, what you expect. All (typical) fitting routines minimize the vertical (y-axis) distance between the fit and the data points to be fit. What you seem to expect is however that it minimizes the euclidean distance between the fit and the data. See the difference in this figure:
[image]

Here see also code that illustrates the fact with random data. Note that the linear relationship of the data (parameter a) is recovered by the fit, which would not be the case for the euclidean fit. Therefore the seemingly off fit is to be prefered.

```
N = 10000
a = -1
b = 0.1

datax = 0.3*b*np.random.randn(N)
datay = a*datax+b*np.random.randn(N)

plot = plt.figure(1,figsize=(10,10)) #Set up the size of the figure
plot.clf()

plt.scatter(datax,datay) #Plot the Cross-Plot

popt = np.polyfit(datax,datay,1)
print("Result is {0:1.2f} and should be {1:1.2f}".format(popt[-2],a))

xplot = np.linspace(-1,1,1000)

def pol(x,popt):
    popt = popt[::-1]
    res = 0
    for i,p in enumerate(popt):
        res += p*x**i
    return res

plt.plot(xplot,pol(xplot,popt))

plt.xlim(-0.3,0.3)
plt.ylim(-0.3,0.3)
plt.xlabel("Intercept")
plt.ylabel("Gradient")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is a good answer, even though it does not explain me, how to make fit that I want =)

Comment: Do you really want the euclidean distance minimized then? What do your points represent and what do you want to learn from the fit?

Comment: This is Intercept and Gradient extracted from Seismic Data. If I will manage to fit it to my trend - I will have a fluid-line equation, which I need for further analysis

Answer (score 0):

samples[0] is your "y" and samples[1] is your "x".  In the trend line plot use samples[1].